# Rails redirect to mobile app using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I specified the URL I wish to redirect to.

```rb
def redirect
  @app_url = "myapp://something"
end
```

In the html template, I tried to change `window.location` using JS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App Redirect</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
        if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
            window.location = <%= @app_url %>
        }
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%= @app_url %></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I go to the page, `app_url` is rendered as a `<h1>` as expected, but I do not get prompted to open the mobile app.

But if I use `window.location = "myapp://something"` instead, everything works as intended as I get prompted to open the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location = "<%= @deep_url %>"` worked